# What to do when another person's question marked as a duplicate isn't really a duplicate?

Tags: discussion

I was recently writing a script where I needed to be able to present a list of currently connected USB storage devices for user selection. I searched for a way to list connected storage devices, and found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168650/how-do-i-list-all-storage-devices-thumb-drives-external-hard-drives-that-are-c?s=1%7C0.8390) (call it question A) which is marked as a duplicate of [another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166420/how-to-detect-an-usb-device) (call it question B). In fact, the question is not a duplicate. It is similar but distinct in that the OP of question A is looking for a way to list only currently connected USB *storage* devices. Question B does not ask how to list connected USB *storage* devices. It is more generic in listing any type of USB device and only upon insertion. Question B presents a distinctly different scenario with potentially very different applications.

I found a solution to question A, but I am unable to post that solution because question A is marked as a duplicate. My solution is not a valid answer to question B. What should I do? Is it possible to request that question A be reopened so that I can post my answer? If so, how do I go about doing that? Should I just re-ask question A so I can post my own answer? Is there another approach to take?

Comment: Can you not post a comment as to why it should be reopened and then vote to reopen it?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix VTR needs 3k rep, IIRC. b_laoshi I'll cast the reopen vote, you leave the comment as Win suggests.

Comment: Huh, what do you know. Gold tag badge FTW!

Comment: b_lasoshi It appears you can post your answer now. Not sure what FTW means other than....nvm.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix For The Win I think (muru was able to singlehandedly undupe the post due to having a gold badge in one of its tags)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix must be fhat the wuck :)

Answer (score 1):

One  way would be to post a comment as to why it should be re-opened (As indicated by @WinEunuuchs2Unix in [this comment](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17211/what-to-do-when-another-persons-question-marked-as-a-duplicate-isnt-really-a-d#comment35525_17211). Having done so you can attempt to draw Votes To REopen by making a request [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) provided you have a rep of 20 or higher.